# Integration on $ \int \sec^3 (2x) dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

The answer is this but the coefficient is $\frac{1}{4}$. Why?

My steps:

$$\int \sec^3(2x)dx$$

Let $u = 2x$, then $\frac{1}{2}du = dx$

$$\frac{1}{2} \int \sec^3(u) du $$

Using int my parts: Let $a = \sec(u)$, then $da = \sec(u)\tan(u)du$. let $dv = \sec^2 (u) du$, then $v = \tan(u)$

$$\frac{1}{2} \int \sec^3(u) du = \frac{1}{2}\big(\sec(u)\tan(u) - \int \sec(u)\tan^2(u)du\big)$$

$$= \frac{1}{2}\big(\tan(u)\sec(u) - \int \sec^3 (u)du + \int \sec(u)du\big)$$

$$\frac{1}{2} \int \sec^3(u)du + \frac{1}{2} \int \sec^3(u)du = \frac{1}{2}\big(\tan(2x)\sec(2x) + \ln |\sec(2x)+\tan(2x)|\big) + C$$

$$\int \sec^3(2x)dx = \frac{1}{2}\big(\tan(2x)\sec(2x) + \ln |\sec(2x)+\tan(2x)|\big) + C$$

Comment: Just a LaTex tip, for trig functions or log functions if you put a \ in front of them, they look better. Compare $\ln(x)$ to $ln(x)$ and $\tan(x)$ to $tan(x)$.

Comment: Thank you. Will keep in mind next time

Comment: Sorry to take your edit but I had to fix a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you derived is that $\int \sec^3 (u)~du=\text{blah}$. Then note that $\int \sec^3(2x)~dx=\frac12\int \sec^3(u)~du$

Comment: oh that makes sense. Thx